# How to show that this complex equation has 10 non real roots and how to express them

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

---

I did the first part successfully:

$$w^{12}=1= \cos 2\pi + i \sin 2\pi$$

$$w= \cos \frac{\pi k}{6} + i \sin \frac{\pi k}{6}$$

> Where $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11$

---

I struggled with this for a long time, I know that the two real roots are $z=2$ and $z=-2$

But how do I prove it and show it can be expressed as that. Please  help.

*Im new to these types  of questions*

---

I only know how to do this when its something like:

$$w^4=1$$

Where there is a the number $1$ or $-1$ and one sided equation. Because then I can write

$$w^4-1=0$$

$$(w-1)(w+1)(w^2+1)=0$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By writing the second equation as
$$\Bigl(\frac{z+2}{z}\Bigr)^{12}=1$$
it reduces to the first.  Therefore the solutions are
$$\frac{z+2}{z}=\cos\frac{k\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{6}\tag{$*$}$$
for $k=0$ or $k=6$ or $k=\pm1,\pm2,\ldots,\pm5$.  Now $k=0$ gives
$$\frac{z+2}{z}=1$$
which is impossible, and $k=6$ gives
$$\frac{z+2}{z}=-1$$
which has the real solution $z=-1$.  So this leaves ten non-real solutions.  You can find them from $(*)$ and do a bit of simplification using trig functions in order to arrive at the given answers.  Specifically, solve for $z$, rationalise the denominator and use half-angle formulae:
$$\eqalign{z
  &=-\frac{2}{1-(\cos\frac{k\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{6})}\cr
  &=-2\frac{(1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{6})+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{6}}
    {(1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{6})^2+(\sin\frac{k\pi}{6})^2}\cr
  &=\cdots\cr
  &=-\frac{(1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{6})+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{6}}{1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{6}}
    \cr
  &=-1-i\frac{2\sin\frac{k\pi}{12}\cos\frac{k\pi}{12}}{2\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{12}}
    \ .\cr}$$
In fact, if you are familiar with complex exponentials you can write $(*)$ as
$$\frac{z+2}{z}=e^{k\pi i/6}$$
and the algebra becomes much easier.

**Comment**.  Worth a thought: including the real solution, we have $11$ solutions.  Can you explain why this is so, when your original equation involved polynomials of degree $12$?  Why are there not $12$ solutions?

Comment: (+1) :D Thank you very much David :) Im in the middle of the working from where Mike left off :D After I finish I will do your method (non subsituting method)

Comment: Oh interesting question :o Why ? :o

Comment: Have a closer look at your original equation - in particular, what do you get if you expand the left hand side?

Comment: Oh got it :D the 12th power gets cancelled off ;) both sides of the equation has $z^{12}$

Comment: That's right.  So it's really degree $11$ after all.

Comment: David , Im really having a hard time expressing it as that expression, For that I think I need to factorize this equation, but now there is an impossible root, how do I factorize this ? I would really appreciate if you can add that to your answer

Comment: It would be very very helpful for me :)

Comment: Actually I have got to this point :

Comment: $z=\frac{2}{cos \frac{\pi k }{6}+ i sin \frac{\pi k}{6} -1 }$ with mikes method, which I still don't know how to continue. Whereas through UR method , there are no Subsituiting , how do I do this the way you did it ?

Comment: See updated answer - a couple of bits still left for you to do.

Comment: Thank you very much :D yes I will :) oh btw your from UNSW Australia , which is a wonderful university (y) :) And Im starting undergrad in Univ of adelaide next feb :)

Comment: @Quincunx It's degree $11$ because if you expand and collect everything on the LHS there is no longer any $z^{12}$ term.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Real root $\implies\sin\dfrac{\pi k}6=0\iff \dfrac{\pi k}6=n\pi\iff k=6n$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: I understood what you said, but I can't figure out how to carry on

Comment: @TheArtist, $$0\le6n\le11\iff n=0,1$$

Comment: (+1) Thank you so much :) But I really don't how to use your results :/ , However I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $w=1/z$. Then

$$(z+2)^{12}=z^{12}\implies (1+2w)^{12}=1$$

Comment: And then I should again substitute $x=1+2w$ ? :) is that correct? :)